# My freebsd system is runngin too slow. Top shows everything fine

Tags: freebsd

My freebsd system is running too slow.

Why I think it is running slow:
Even an `ls` command take 2 sec to execute, 20MB folder is taking forever to delete.

Top shows everything fine.

```
last pid:   892;  load averages:  0.05,  0.03,  0.00                                                                                                                                up 0+00:20:49  07:11:53
29 processes:  1 running, 28 sleeping
CPU:  0.0% user,  0.0% nice,  0.1% system,  0.0% interrupt, 99.9% idle
Mem: 29M Active, 25M Inact, 489M Wired, 233M Buf, 31G Free
Swap: 96G Total, 96G Free

  PID USERNAME    THR PRI NICE   SIZE    RES STATE   C   TIME    WCPU COMMAND
  874 nchinde       1  20    0 29072K 22084K biowr   1   0:05   0.26% svn
  892 root          1  20    0  7912K  3476K CPU0    0   0:00   0.03% top
  656 root          1  20    0 13176K  7744K select  3   0:00   0.00% sshd
  768 nchinde       1  20    0  7476K  3224K pause   2   0:00   0.00% screen
  674 nchinde       1  20    0 13176K  7764K select  0   0:00   0.00% sshd
  769 nchinde       1  20    0  9528K  4844K select  2   0:00   0.00% screen
  659 root          1  20    0  6532K  2552K wait    3   0:00   0.00% bash
  770 nchinde       1  20    0  6532K  2556K wait    0   0:00   0.00% bash
  671 root          1  21    0 13176K  7688K select  2   0:00   0.00% sshd
  514 root          1  20    0 21528K  6948K sbwait  2   0:00   0.00% lldpd
  675 nchinde       1  20    0  7056K  2996K wait    2   0:00   0.00% sh
  519 _lldpd        1  20    0 21528K  7104K kqread  0   0:00   0.00% lldpd
  435 root          1  20    0  6428K  2444K select  3   0:00   0.00% syslogd
```

I tried to resart, but not luck

Comment: Have you checked the SSD/HDD for SMART or file system errors?

Comment: Could you define “running slow”? Do you simply experience _a delay_ when invoking `top(1)`, but the program itself _runs smoothly_ (regular display updates, responds to keyboard interactions without delays)? With a vanilla installation I’d suspect the hardware is faulty, too. Or does the _program itself_ run slowly? Maybe using `truss(1)` you could spot a system call that is taking unusually long. I can attest the programmers of `ls(1)` have not inserted any code artificially slowing down execution, so the reason for “running slow” _must_ lie _outside_ of `ls(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

The two symptoms you listed:

1. `ls` takes a long time.
2. Directory-removal takes a long time.

both point at the storage (also known as "disk") and/or filesystem problem(s). You'd need to research, how to speed these things up to match your needs.

Further, your `top`-snapshot shows Subversion running -- and busy in the `biowr`-state, which points at the same. Subversion can be quite heavy on the storage -- if you try other operations exercising the same storage-device Subversion is currently updating, you may be slowed down just by that.

The good news is, only the I/O is delayed -- the rest of your system is idle and could, for example, be used to play a movie, compile something, or, indeed, manage the LLDP-information.

None of this is FreeBSD-specific, though...